# How to identify mentions in a text?

Tags: english, computational-linguistics, nlp

I am looking for rule-based methods or any other methods to identify all mentions in a text. I have found several libraries that give coreferences but no exact options for only mentions. What I want is something like below:

Input text:

> [This painter]'s indulgence of visual fantasy, and appreciation of different historic architectural styles can be seen in his 1840 Architect's Dream. After a series of paintings on The Last of the Mohicans, [he] made a three year trip to Europe in 1829, but [he] is better known for a trip four years earlier in which [he] journeyed up the Hudson River to the Catskill Mountains. FTP, name [this painter of The Oxbow] and The Voyage of Life series.

*The square brackets highlight mentions.

Please suggest a way to deal with this. Also, how is it different from coreferences? It would be really helpful if someone could post links to the concerned papers.

Comment: This *is* coreference. It is exactly what coreference resolution is intended to do. "This painter" coreferences "he", etc.

Comment: Thank you Adam_G for your reply. But my problem is little different as I want all the mentions. Does coreference gives all the mentions? Actually when I tried Stanford core nlp coreference module, it was giving me only co-referent mentions and not all.

Comment: It is extremely difficult to understand what you're looking for. Coreference resolution is a hard task, and is not 100% robust. I'd encourage you to do some reading about the topic, and then submit a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Does "any other method" include manual work? Then I recommend to train some students to annotate the *coreference chains*. Take care that every text is annotated twice by different annotators, and compute the *inter-annotator agreement* (e.g., by determining *Cohen's kappa*).